# Problem with Kubernetes nginx ingress custom errors and auth-signin combination

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I was looking to find out about custom error pages. I have set the `--default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/custom-errors` to point to the service and then also the `custom-http-errors` config map property.

Pretty straight forward and all working as expected.

My problem appears to be on ingress' with the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin`

**WITH the annotation**:

1. If you are logged in, then you get the standard default error page for all errors (the one that I don’t want)
2. If you are not logged in, you are **correctly** redirected to auth.

**WITHOUT the annotation**:

1. If you are logged in, then you get the **correct** custom error pages
2. If you are not logged in, you now get a standard default 401 error page instead of the sign-in URL

I can only seem to get one or the other, depending on the above.. Ideally what I’m looking for is a combination of the above, i.e.

1. If you are logged in, then you get the **correct** custom error pages
   (correct WITHOUT annotation)
2. If you are not logged in, you are
   **correctly** redirected to auth. (correct WITH annotation)

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem ? Could you share your ingress resource yaml ? Additionally knowing how you installed your nginx-ingress controller (specific options) would be helpful in reproducing your issue.

Comment: I did manage to get it part of the way there - - the solution was to add ` nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-http-errors: "502,503,504"` to each of the ingress routes that are protected by the auth-url annotations. Not sure why this is necessary - however this seems to work around the issue that I queried.